# How to return 'NULL' in fields with no input in SQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a table that has the following columns: year, city, country, avg_temp.

I am trying to write a query that extracts the data into a CSV, but I want the fields with no input to show NULL for avg_temp.

Comment: `SELECT IF(columnName IS NULL, 'NULL', columnName)  as columnName FROM table`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check in the select with

```
CASE WHEN avg_temp IS NULL THEN 'NULL' ELSE avg_temp END AS avg_temp
```

Or with if

```
IF (avg_temp IS NULL, 'NULL', avg_temp) AS avg_temp
```